# AWS Lambda: Calling the Invoke API failed with message: [object Object]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Today, all my Lambda function tests (in the AWS Lambda Console) have been yielding the following message:

> Calling the Invoke API failed with message: [object Object]

Is anyone else experiencing this? It seems to work fine from the aws cli (and my context seems to be identical).

Comment: I mean the problem here is that your logging is bad. That message generated by your code. Can you provide a part of code that you are using?

Comment: seems like it's on AWS side. The code runs fine and does everything it needs to do. It also provides a log. This is also code that was providing output just fine yesterday.

Comment: Did you figure out a resolution for this? I notice that I get this issue only on my Firefox Nightly edition, and not in Edge, or Chrome browsers. I also notice an error in the Firefox console "TypeError: asm.js type error: Disabled by 'asmjs' runtime option rusha.min.js"

Comment: Ah perhaps they try a webassembly solution on selected browsers that doesn't work, or Firefox' is broken