# AWS Lambda: Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: [object Object]

Tags: firefox, aws-lambda

This question has a few more details, in addition to the report here: [AWS Lambda: Calling the Invoke API failed with message: [object Object]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52498213/aws-lambda-calling-the-invoke-api-failed-with-message-object-object)

- When I try to invoke my Lambda function, by clicking on "Test" button, I see the error reported.
- Issue seen on browser: Firefox Nightly 64.0a1 (2018-10-15) (64-bit), on a Windows 10 system.In the browser console, I see this error:
  `TypeError: asm.js type error: Disabled by 'asmjs' runtime option   rusha.min.js`
- In the Network tab, of the Firefox dev-tools, I see that the invocation returns with a `403` error. The response is : 
  `{"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."}`

Everything works as expected on Microsoft Edge, and Chrome browsers.

Comment: Please refer : https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/t/the-request-signature-we-calculated-does-not-match-the-signature-you-provid/256395

Comment: @iftekhardani, thanks for the link. But then, am not sure I have any control over creating the signature. In any case this works as expected on Edge, and Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue / bug, that has since been fixed in Firefox Nightly (and should flow into Firefox standard release).
The details of the issue are here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1499136
In Firefox's `about:config`, the key
`dom.xhr.standard_content_type_normalization` is now set to `false` by default.

Answer (score 0):

Asm might be a red herring, but I can believe AWS might well be using it to speed up their signing. This fits, as the error you're seeing occurs when you try to do something on the AWS Api without the v4 signature being correct.

I notice you're using a nightly build of firefox, so you might well be subject to a known bug &c, or asm.js might be disabled for that platform.

Following the error, I suggest you try going to `about:config` (to change your firefox configuration), and set `javascript.options.asmjs` to `true`.

Failing that, you might have to get off the nightly build or raise a bug report.

Comment: thanks for some hints. I tried to disable the asmjs option in `about:config`, to see if that made a difference (it was set to `true` by default) . Also, opened a bug in Firefox Nightly, to see if it unearths anything: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1499746